# Woocommerce Product Images Blurry Tried Everything

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, product, blurry

I hope this community can help. I see there is a lot of information on Woocommerce blurry product images and I've tried the fixes to no avail. We recently migrated our site and although all the products in our shop are fine, each time we try to upload and create a new product, the main product image is blurry.

Here's two examples. (1)  [Good product listing](http://liquescencemedia.com/store/melismatiqks/music-scores-t-shirts-crumbs-agnus-dei/)
And (2) [here's the test with problems](http://liquescencemedia.com/store/uncategorized/test-product-image/)

Using Onetone wordpress theme and have the current installs of Wordpress and Woocommerce. Changing the thumbnail size and regenerating did not solve the problem. Neither did changing the image size from 100% declaration to 'auto' in Woocommerce.

The problem seems to be wordpress is using a much smaller thumbnail (we did not change any sizes after migration) and this is causing the blur because the images are being blown up. Here's the code I found for the image:

The image 'source' for this in particular is:
src="http://liquescencemedia.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Liquescence-Time-Travel-Mens-Ash-Grey-1-275x275.jpg

And as you can see, somehow this size is being used for the product image although we've uploaded a much larger size (1000x1000).

On the image details attachment page everything is fine, the resolution is high.

So I'm quite frustrated with this. Why is it calling a 275x275 from uploads when I've uploaded an image 1000x1000? How can I change this?

Any help is appreciated. Do know that I've already been through the Woocommerce literature and it doesn't address this problem.

Comment: The two links you posted don't look blurry to me. Also what are your product image sizes? (admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=products&section=display)

Comment: Hi Aztec and thanks for your response. My product image are all sized as  275x575. Yeah, they don't look blurry now. It keeps going back and forth from crystal clear to pixelated after I regenerate thumbs. I don't think it's completely sorted out. I added this to woocommerce css:

Comment: Here's code: .woocommerce div.product div.images img {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important; /*changed from 100% 8-8-16 to auto and back - this is original trying to solve blurry product image problem*/
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: none
}

Comment: And yes, we're back to blurry on product gallery and product main images. I'm really tearing my hair out at this point!

Comment: http://liquescencemedia.com/store/axiomomatiqks/dont-let-stupid-people-rent-space-in-your-head/ --> the main image is fine (for now, but it's been changing the last hour), but all the gallery images (all the same size; 1000x1000px were the uploads) are terribly blurry. And it keeps going on and off? What could be causing this inconsistency?

Comment: Still don't see it, but I'd definitely start with reverting to a default theme.

Comment: thanks, I think it's solved the best I can for now.